# Logo pics in emails

Tags: email

i had edited the img in magento admin to

```
<img src="/skin/frontend/midmeds/default/images/logo_email.gif" >
```

and when i preview it in the admin then it looks perfect but when the email is sent out i get this in the img url

```
<img src="https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/YKIbBEKJqXLLRvtsxSg616pv6cdkoOd8DFQj7dIL2VqShNSzBbcneLxTw_fhjOIgxD8K1iwkA5wXfn-y70g_8dPz5Ifw1UWjlb2EaeUK93M=s0-d-e1-ft#http://skin/frontend/midmeds/default/images/logo_email.gif">
```

does anybody know why??

Comment: Can you please add the screenshot what you got into email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a full path to the image. Relative paths won't work because the e-mail client does not know the base url of your website.

Instead of this:

```
<img src="/skin/frontend/midmeds/default/images/logo_email.gif" >
```

try using this:

```
<img src="{{skin url="images/logo_email.gif"}}" />
```